# How to customize the map annotation pin in MKMapView with iPhone?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

Hello friends,

I want to develop a functionality MKMapView in iPhone and to show the custom pin in MKAnnotation so please could anyone provide me a link or any idea about this functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to specify annotation image in the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
        static NSString * const kAnnotationId = @"VumeliveAnnotation";

    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = nil;
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[CustomAnnotation class]])
    {
        annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:kAnnotationId];
        if (annotationView == nil) {
            annotationView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:kAnnotationId] autorelease];
            annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
            annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        }

        [annotationView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:<your image name>]];
    }

    return annotationView;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much give me code but I want to set image instead of default map pin so any idea about that...

Comment: this code is exactly doing this.....it will not add default pin rather the image you give here `[annotationView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:<your image name>]];`

Comment: Thanks and is there any way to set index number on map pin in mapview?? please tell me

Comment: This works on the simulator for me, but doesn't on the actual iPad (iOS 5.0.1).  Any ideas why?

Comment: @JosephDeCarlo you're image might be missing from the bundle resources. Make sure its present in your project folder and added to the bundle resources. If image is missing from one of these two, it appears in simulator but not on device. Hope this helps